# GestureDetector gesture handler app crash when calling external function

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, fling

i tried to use `GestureDetector` of `react-native-gesture-handler`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Directions, Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';

/**
 * Component used as Home Page
 */
const HomePage: React.FC  = () => {
  const position = useSharedValue(0);
  const trigger = () => {
    console.log('fdfs')
  }

  const flingGesture = Gesture.Fling()
    .direction(Directions.RIGHT)
    .onStart((e) => {
      position.value = withTiming(position.value + 10, { duration: 100 });
      console.log(e)
      // trigger()
    });

    const flingGestureLeft = Gesture.Fling()
    .direction(Directions.LEFT)
    .onStart((e) => {
      position.value = withTiming(position.value - 10, { duration: 100 });
      // trigger()
    });

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [{ translateX: position.value }],
  }));

  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={Gesture.Simultaneous(flingGestureLeft, flingGesture)}>
      <Animated.View style={[{ width: 100, height: 30, backgroundColor: 'red' }, animatedStyle]} />
    </GestureDetector>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

this work without problem when i fling my bloc to left or right, but when i tried to call an exeternal function like the `trigger()`, my app crash. Is a bug of the gesture detector or there is something to add?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reanimated, gesture handler hooks and callbacks works on the UI thread and the **trigger** function you defined is by default on the JS thread, so you can not use it directly.

There are two solutions to this:

1. add '[worklet](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/worklets)' in the trigger function as below

```js
    const trigger = () => {
      'worklet'
      console.log('fdfs')
    }
```

2. Or wrap your function with '[runOnJS](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/miscellaneous/runOnJS)' from reanimated as below

```js
    import { runOnJS } from 'react-native-reanimated';

    const flingGesture = Gesture.Fling()
      .direction(Directions.RIGHT)
      .onStart((e) => {
        position.value = withTiming(position.value + 10, { duration: 100 });
        console.log(e)
        runOnJS(trigger)()
      });
```

> Note:- syntax for runOnJS is like 'runOnJS(functionName)(params).
> So if your function takes two params (Ex. 1st number and 2nd string), you would call it like this:- runOnJS(trigger)(1, 'dummyString')

For more details you can read the docs from [reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated) and [gesture-handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs).